# one to many for same entity class in play framework

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1, ebean

Good day!
I am triing to save my Entity model by always get an error

```
Error inserting bean [class models.CategoryEntity] with unidirectional relationship. For inserts you must use cascade save on the master bean [class models.CategoryEntity].]
```

Here my class

```
@Entity
public class CategoryEntity extends Model {
    @Id
    private String categoryId;

    private String Name;
    private Integer level;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = CategoryEntity.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<CategoryEntity> categories;
//GETERS SETRES
}
```

I tried to save the header category, but error is the same

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly and what you want is that each CategoryEntity contains a list of other CategoryEntities, 2 possible approaches come to mind (although none of them use @OneToMany):

**Approach 1:**
You could create a @ManyToMany relationship and define a @JoinTable whilst naming its keys:

```
@Entity
public class CategoryEntity extends Model {
    @Id
    private String categoryId;

    private String name;
    private Integer level;

    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(         name = "category_category",
                 joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "source_category_id"), 
          inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "target_category_id"))
    public List<CategoryEntity> category_entity_lists = new ArrayList<CategoryEntity>();
}
```

**Approach 2:**
Or you could create a new entity for the list of category entities and create a @ManyToMany relationship, e.g.:

```
@Entity
public class CategoryList extends Model
{
    @Id
    public Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="categorylist_category")
    public List<CategoryEntity> category_list = new ArrayList<CategoryEntity>();
}
```

And then in your model:

```
@Entity
public class CategoryEntity extends Model {
    @Id
    private String categoryId;

    private String name;
    private Integer level;

    @OneToOne
    public CategoryList this_category_list;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="category_list")
    public List<CategoryList> in_other_category_lists = new ArrayList<CategoryList>();
}
```

Didn't test the code, but what this should do is that each CategoryEntity can be part of several CategoryLists. Each CategoryList contains a list of CategoryEntities.

You would have to initialize this_category_list and add CategoryEntities to its category_list field.

Comment: @nabiullinas which approach did you succeed with?

Answer (score -3):

Your model doesnt make sense.
why do you have as class attribute the class itself?

the List should not be in the same class

Comment: Why not? A person entity could have friends, other persons